Capitalization of popular place-names: Should "the Valley" be capitalized?
I have a question about the following that CMOS and an additional name listed that I put asterisks right next to the following:

the Cape*
the Delta--round out name of region in a state
the Gulf--may cap if written with Atlantic, for instance
Long Island -> the Island*
the Loop (Chicago)
Midtown (Manhattan)
the Village*? (Greenwich Village)--may have seen capped in a geographic dictionary--may be OK

Also, the valley in my area (Horse Creek Valley) plus many other valleys scattered across the US are being referred to as "the Valley." However, my area, I've seen as "the valley." So which is right? Also, I think the whole thing is bogus, especially if each noun could literally mean "the valley" as a common noun or geographical term types, such as "the cape" or "the village," for instance.
It seems to be that I would need to consult a specific geographic dictionary, right?

Are you asking if specific places like your Valley are not the valley? Yes, the difference is not bogus.

If something is a valley it's common to refer to it as "the valley". But it's also common to abbreviate proper names, keeping capitalization. See this question about Central Park, New York.

Greenwich Village is not a village; it’s a neighborhood.
